# Why the content type of a mp4 video can be text/plain?

Tags: java, html, url, content-type, multimedia

I was developing an application which can receive a url of a file, and should do different things depending on the type of the file (audio, video, image). So I'm getting the content type of the file in this way:

```
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
String contentType = connection.getContentType();
```

I've tried with some jpg and mp3 files and the content type is the expected one, but I'm having a problem with a video in this web (I just used it by chance) http://www.yo-yo.org/mp4/ I've tried it with the video TestFour (http://www.yo-yo.org/mp4/yu5.mp4) and I'm getting the following content-type:

```
text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

I expected to get "video/mp4".

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this content type?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have also tried with another video at [http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/mp4/claw_pix_example01_movie.mp4](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/mp4/claw_pix_example01_movie.mp4) and it happens the same.

Also the same with http://www.easydnnsolutions.com/Portals/0/EasyGalleryImages/1/18/Alice_in_Wonderland_Teaser_1.mp4

In all of them I'm getting the same content type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The server MIME configuration is likely incorrect and the source of the problem.

Comment: I've tried it with three different pages and all of them are returning the same content type. Or it is a very common mistake in the server MIME configuration or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It is very possible that it could be common. Do you have access to the server admin?

Comment: the server admin? The pages where the videos are placed are not mine. I've just googled for .mp4 example files just to try, but with no luck.

Comment: OK. Its very likely that its not common.